# Детектор границ Кенни (Canny Edge) [Threshold, Kernel size]

Tags: opencv

Всем привет !

Начал разбираться с детектором распознавания границ `Сanny Edge`. Общую картину (хоть и на очень поверхностном уровне) я немного понял, но не могу сообразить, для чего нужны такие понятия как:

1. Threshold (пороги) - есть минимум и максимум.
2. Kernel size (сетка) - вот [тут](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) в примере они используют величину
   **3x3**

И еще вопрос, может кто нибудь подскажет литературу на эту тему ? Мне очень интересно, как это работает. Все, что я нашел - [это вот это](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/484.html), [с документации библиотеки OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) и с [вот этой неплохой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114589/).  Спасибо !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пороги (`threshold`) - это произвольные значения, используемые алгоритмом Кэнни для принятия решения по каждому из пикселей на заключительном этапе своей работы. Порогов всего два: верхний и нижний.

Если значение магнитуды градиента каждого отдельного пикселя оказывается больше верхнего порога, то такой пиксель считается границей. Если значение магнитуды градиента оказывается меньше нижнего порога, то такой пиксель отбрасывается (более не учитывается).

Если же значение магнитуды градиента пикселя оказывается между порогами, то в этой ситуации в различных реализациях алгоритма проводят либо отдельную проверку, ориентируясь на значения и направления градиента у смежных пикселей, либо, как это имеет место быть в OpenCV, помечают его в качестве границы при условии, что рассматриваемый пиксель соседствует с пикселем, имеющим значение магнитуды градиента больше верхнего порога.

Размер ядра (`kernel size` или `aperture size`) - это размер квадратных матриц свёртки (`convolution`), которые используются для вычисления градиента на вертикальном и горизонтальном направлениях. В случае с OpenCV допустимыми значениями размера ядра могут быть только "3", "5" или "7". Эту функцию выполняет оператор Собеля, который прозрачно вызывается в функции `Canny()`.

Свёртка в отношении изображений - это по сути операция вычисления нового значения для каждого пикселя на основе значений других пикселей, являющихся ему соседями. В свёртке, помимо самого изображения, участвует отдельная матрица, зачастую называемая окном или фильтром. Обычно используют квадратную, с равным, но при этом нечётным количеством строк и колонок. Нечётность нужна для того, чтобы в общем случае получить центральный элемент матрицы или, иначе, так называемый якорь:

```
( )( )( )
( )(x)( )
( )( )( )
```

В процессе свёртки на каждый пиксель исходного изображения как бы накладывается якорь, тем самым накрывая фильтром и все соседние у текущего пиксели. Затем вычисляется сумма произведений значений пикселей на значения соответствующих элементов фильтра, что и будет являться новым значением пикселя.

Comment: Почему то так и знал, что именно Вы ответите ! Спасибо огромное, хорошего дня :)

Comment: Спасибо :) На самом деле участников на ru.so, кто хорошо разбирается в тематике компьютерного зрения, очень много. Просто вопросы в последнее время стали редки и соответственно активность в ответах упала по сравнению с более ранним периодом. Но мне кажется, что это дело постепенно поправится, если хотя бы даже и одному стараться в ответах принимать активное участие. Посмотрим :)